# Search from database from multiple tables using mvc and oracle

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, oracle, search

I have a requirement, where I am not able to trace how to make this functionality. Because here what I want is.

I will have a search Icon, on click of which a `textbox` will be opened. Now user can insert any *text* into the `textbox` and on search click, *it will search from the tables of the databases which consist of 12-15 tables in oracle*

So my issue here is, how to proceed this with and is it logically correct to do like this. Or please suggest any other way to implement this.

Please suggest

**UPDATE**

> I have done this for One table, but I want this to work for as many tables I have in future.

```
PROCEDURE GET_SEARCH_DATA
 (
  P_INPUTTEXT IN NVARCHAR2,
  P_RETURN OUT SYS_REFCURSOR 
 )

AS

BEGIN
   OPEN P_RETURN FOR

 SELECT DISTINCT APP_MST_ID, APPLICATIONNAME, PROJECTNO, VSS_FOLDER_LOC 
   FROM APPLICATION_MASTER 
  WHERE APPLICATIONNAME LIKE  '%'|| P_INPUTTEXT || '%'
     OR PROJECTNO LIKE '%' ||  P_INPUTTEXT || '%'
     OR VSS_FOLDER_LOC LIKE '%' ||  P_INPUTTEXT || '%';

END;
```

Comment: Which columns in all tables are you wanting to search? all of them ? ids, dates,numbers, or is there some segmented set ?

Comment: @KrisRice: Almost all coumns, except Id's and dates wont be searched. can u help me with this ?

Comment: So, some questions: 1. Is it necessary to have a procedure with `SYS_REFCURSOR` out parameter? 2. Do you need to do this search in all 15 tables with only one request to DB?

Comment: @Dmitry: No, its not necessary, I just added so that I can return some value and show in front end. and for your second question, yes because there might be data in any table so how should I do for that. ?

Comment: I've read the question once again, it seems I didn't notice before: if in the future a new table will appear, the query should work with it too, right? In this case, how do you define, in which table you have to search? In all tables of a certain schema or any another way?

Comment: @Dmitry: there is a slight change now in my requirement after a discussion with my manager. I will update you today later in sometime. so that we can co ordinate and create a query/procedure for this.

Comment: Doing this approach of querying X tables will not scale well. User will most certainly log an ER to speed it up. More table, more data will kill the performance.

Comment: Did you use `Entity Framework`?

Comment: @Dmitry: can u come here online for discussion on this topic. so that we can discuss and find a solution for it.. https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164954/oracledb-discussion

Comment: @Dmitry: can u come on chat.. ?

Comment: @Dmitry: let me know if u can come, so that I can update you on this.

Comment: I don't know, how to write there. There was only a link to request the access which I clicked. So you have to approve it, right?

Comment: @vvv did you update the question with your new requirements?

Comment: @Dmitry yes but we will see it tomorrow as I left office for the day..I was waiting whole day for ur response.never mind will see it tomorrow. Have a good day

Comment: @Dmitry: I have given you the access for the chat link. now u can also text and access the chat. Let me know once you come

Comment: @Dmitry: let  me know when are u going to come.. ?

Comment: I'm almost there... Wait a minute.

Comment: ok..come on chat directly/.

Comment: I posted an answer to your second question. Whan you asked me, I almost finished. Do you need anything else or that is OK?

Comment: yes, i need something else but related to this. if u can come on chat than I can explain you better https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164954/oracledb-discussion

Comment: @Dmitry: can we discuss on this now ?

Answer (score 2):

15 tables * 10 columns each = 150 columns (for example). Which ones of them do you want to search? All of them? Only some of them?

If ALL, you'd loop through all tables and columns (USER_TABLES joined with USER_TAB_COLUMNS) and search for that string. If SOME of the columns, you'd include those columns into the WHERE clause of the cursor FOR loop's SELECT statement. Any option you choose, it smells like a dynamic SQL.

Here's an example of how I'm doing it, searching all tables that have a column named TELEPHONE (telephone number); search string is "654" with the LIKE operator, so that it returns all tables that contain the TELEPHONE column and telephone number contains 654. The result is displayed with the DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (as I'm running it from SQL*Plus). Your output will, probably, be something else.

Have a look, adjust it if necessary.

```
DECLARE
  l_str VARCHAR2(500);
  l_cnt NUMBER := 0;
BEGIN
  FOR cur_r IN (SELECT u.table_name, u.column_name
                FROM user_tab_columns u, user_tables t
                WHERE u.table_name = t.table_name
                  AND u.column_name = 'TELEPHONE'
                                                            )
  LOOP
    l_str := 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ' || cur_r.table_name ||
             ' WHERE ' || cur_r.column_name || ' like (''%654%'')';

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE (l_str) INTO l_cnt;

    IF l_cnt > 0 THEN
       dbms_output.put_line(l_cnt ||' : ' || cur_r.table_name);
    END IF;                         
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: thanks for your reply and answer, but is this the accurate way to do this or do you have any other way for implementing this ? any suggestion would be welcomed

Comment: Well, that's how I do it. Someone else might suggest another approach, so - be patient.

Answer (score 0):

You can also create a table that has two columns,

```
CREATE TABLE table1
(value_col VARCHAR2(4000), query_col VARCHAR2(4000));
```

Use the PL/SQL Littlefoot did, modify it  a little bit so that it will insert data to the table

So, if you perform a search you will just have to use query like below

```
SELECT query_col
  FROM table1
 WHERE value_col LIKE '%'||INPUT_TEXT||'%';
```

And for the query_col value, you can use it to get the REF CURSOR records and display it in your front end.

Answer (score 0):

According your searching on one table, you should use union all like this below.

```
select c1, c2, c3, c4 from (
    select distinct column1 as c1, column2 as c2, column3 as c3, column4 as c4
    from table1 where column1 like '%'|| para ||'%' or column2 like '%'|| para ||'%' or column3 like '%'|| para ||'%' or column4 like '%'|| para ||'%'
    union all
    select distinct  column1 as c1, column2 as c2, column3 as c3, '' as c4
    from table2 where column1 like '%'|| para ||'%' or column2 like '%'|| para ||'%' or column3 like '%'|| para ||'%'
    union all
    select distinct  column1 as c1, column2 as c2, column3 as c3, '' as c4
    from table3 where column1 like '%'|| para ||'%' or column2 like '%'|| para ||'%' or column3 like '%'|| para ||'%'
)tbl.
```

Hope this will help.